# Collision Calculation in 2D

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity, collision, angular-velocity

For a 2D physics simulation, I need to resolve collisions between two objects in 2D. I have available each object's initial angular velocity, linear velocity, mass, moment of inertia, and center of mass. For the collision, I have available the point of contact and coefficient of restitution. How do I calculate each object's final angular and linear velocity?

What I've tried:
[This thread on calculating the angular velocity given initial and final velocities](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/759521/finding-the-angular-velocity-of-an-object-after-a-collision)
[This Wikipedia page on elastic collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects)

Comment: Hi Jcsq6. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is clearly a conceptual question rather than a homework question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Do the 3D body collision](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/783565/392) but only allow motion along the *xy* plane and rotations about the *z* axis. In the link therein there is a link to a very important paper about computer simulations of rigid bodies which you can reference for your own benefit.

Follow the following steps:

0. **Definitions** - Two bodies, each with mass $m_1$ and $m_2$, mass moment of inertia at each center of mass of $I_1$ and $I_2$ with CoM position vectors $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$, and velocity vectors $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$, as well as rotation (scalars) $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$.

   [image: fig1]

   <sub>Contacting bodies definitions for the general 3D case.</sub>
1. **Contact Properties** - The contact happens at a location $\vec{r}_A$, and along the perpendicular (normal) direction of $\hat{n}$ shown above as acting on body #2 and reacting on body #1.

   $$\begin{aligned}
    \vec{r}_1 & = \pmatrix{x_1 \\ y_1} & \vec{r}_2 & = \pmatrix{x_2 
    \\ y_2} & \vec{r}_A & = \pmatrix{x_A \\ y_A} \\
     \vec{v}_1 & = \pmatrix{\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{y}_1} & \vec{v}_2 & = 
     \pmatrix{\dot{x}_2 \\ \dot{y}_2} & \hat{n} & = \pmatrix{n_x \\ n_y}
   \end{aligned}$$
2. **Impact Speed** - Work out the relative velocities of the two bodies at the contact point, and project the velocity along the contact normal to get the impact speed.

   $$ \begin{gathered}v_{{\rm imp}}=n_{x}\left(\dot{x}_{1}+\omega_{1}(y_{1}-y_{A})-\dot{x}_{2}-\omega_{2}(y_{2}-y_{A})\right)+\\
   +n_{y}\left(\dot{y}_{1}+\omega_{1}(x_{A}-x_{1})-\dot{y}_{2}-\omega_{2}(x_{A}-x_{2})\right)
   \end{gathered} \tag{1} $$
3. **Reduced Mass** - This is the effective mass the contact feels and it is used to calculate the impulse magnitude to make the objects bounce of each other.

   $$m_{{\rm imp}}=\frac{1}{\tfrac{1}{m_{1}}+\tfrac{\left(n_{x}(y_{1}-y_{A})+n_{y}(x_{A}-x_{1})\right)^{2}}{I_{1}}+\tfrac{1}{m_{2}}+\tfrac{\left(n_{x}(y_{2}-y_{A})+n_{y}(x_{A}-x_{2})\right)^{2}}{I_{2}}} \tag{2}$$
4. **Impulse Magnitude** - Impact calculations are 1D along the contact normal, and this gives us exactly how much momentum is exchanged between the objects

   $$ J = (1+\epsilon) \, m_{\rm imp} \, v_{\rm imp} \tag{3} $$

   The contact is characterized by the coefficient of restitution $\epsilon$.
5. **Impulse Response** - Each object changes its motion parameters instantaneously according to the following expressions

   $$\small \begin{aligned}\Delta\dot{x}_{1} & =-\frac{n_{x}}{m_{1}}\,J & \Delta\dot{x}_{2} & =+\frac{n_{x}}{m_{2}}\,J\\
   \Delta\dot{y}_{1} & =-\frac{n_{y}}{m_{1}}\,J & \Delta\dot{y}_{2} & =+\frac{n_{y}}{m_{2}}\,J\\
   \Delta\omega_{1} & =-\frac{n_{x}(y_{1}-y_{A})+n_{y}(x_{A}-x_{1})}{I_{1}}\,J & \Delta\omega_{2} & =+\frac{n_{x}(y_{2}-y_{A})+n_{y}(x_{A}-x_{2})}{I_{2}}\,J
   \end{aligned} \tag{4}$$
6. **Simulation** - Continue the simulation after assigning the new motion parameters to the objects

   $$\begin{aligned}\dot{x}_{1} & \leftarrow\dot{x}_{1}+\Delta\dot{x}_{1} & \dot{x}_{2} & \leftarrow\dot{x}_{2}+\Delta\dot{x}_{2}\\
   \dot{y}_{1} & \leftarrow\dot{y}_{1}+\Delta\dot{y}_{1} & \dot{y}_{2} & \leftarrow\dot{y}_{2}+\Delta\dot{y}_{2}\\
   \omega_{1} & \leftarrow\omega_{1}+\Delta\omega_{1} & \omega_{2} & \leftarrow\omega_{2}+\Delta\omega_{2}
   \end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

you can use those equations

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

Translation
\begin{align*}
 &\b v_1=-\frac{\lambda}{m_1}\,\b n+\b u_1 \\
&\b v_2=+\frac{\lambda}{m_2}\,\b n+\b u_2 
\end{align*}

Rotation
\begin{align*}
 &\b\omega_1=\b\Omega_1-\lambda\,\b q_1\\
 &\b\omega_2=\b\Omega_2-\lambda\,\b q_2
\end{align*}
Energy equation
\begin{align*}
 [(\b v_2-\b v_1)+\epsilon(\b u_2-\b u_1)]\cdot \b n+
 [(\b\omega_2\cdot \b q_2-\b \omega_1\cdot \b q_1)+
 \epsilon(\b \Omega_2\cdot \b q_2-\b\Omega_1\cdot\b q_1)]=0
\end{align*}

where
\begin{align*}
 &\b q_1=\frac{1}{I_1}\,(\b r_1\times \b n)_z\\
 &\b q_2=\frac{1}{I_2}\,(\b r_2\times \b n)_z\\
\end{align*}

unknowns are the x,y components of the velocities $~\b v_i~$ after the  collision, the angular velocities $\omega_i~$ and $~\lambda~$ , altogether 7 unknowns. to solve the problem , you obtained 4 translation equations, 2 rotation equations and the energy equation, altogether 7 equations

Input

- $~\b u_i~$ velocities x,y components bevor collision
- $~\Omega_i~$ angular velocities bevor collision
- $~\b n~$ unit collision normal vector
- $~\b r_i~$ vector from the collision point to the center of mass
- $~I_i~$ Inertia of the bodies about the z axes
- $~m_i~$ Bodies mass
- $~\epsilon~$ restoration coefficient $~0 \le \epsilon\le 1~$

Output

- $~v_i~$ Center of mass velocities after collision
- $~\omega_i~$ angular velocities after collision